# Common ID between Google Drive API and Google Picasa API

Tags: google-drive-api, picasa

Google Picasa API and Google Drive API let us access our photos. I would like to use these two APIs in one application but these two APIs don't seem to give common photos ID.
Does anybody know a solution to make sure that a Picasa photo and a Drive file target the same photo ?
Do I need to make an equal function based on the photo name and its year (the name alone is not enough)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `ViewId` is an ID common to Google Drive and Google Picasa and this ID can be used or it's equivalent class with [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/).

With this API, you can create a `Picker` object using a `PickerBuilder` object. As stated,

> A `Picker` renders one view at a time. Specify at least one view, either by ID (`google.​picker.​ViewId.*`) or by creating an instance of a type (`google.​picker.​*View`).

Furthermore, to show Picasa Web Album's Featured Photos gallery

> Use a class instance instead of the `ViewId` when you need type-specific control.

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
    addView(new google.picker.PhotosView().
        setType(google.picker.PhotosView.Type.FEATURED)).
    setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
    setCallback(pickerCallback).
    build();
```

Likewise, to handle Google Drive items

> The picker interface can display a list of the currently authenticated user's Google Drive files. When a user selects a file from the list, the file ID is returned, and the ID may be used by an app to access the file.

```
// Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
    function createPicker() {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .addView(view)
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
         picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

For better understanding and for detailed information regarding this API, please try going through the given documentation. You may also refer to table in [Showing Different Views](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews) if you need to know which equivalent class you can use instead of using`ViewId`.